# How can I effectively get attention to Round Two of a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted [Why would cookies be vanishing in IE6/8, and what can I do about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060229/why-would-cookies-be-vanishing-in-ie6-8-and-what-can-i-do-about-it), a question about a problem with cookies in IE for a PHP site, without the best diagnostics to start off with. One user said that it was hard to tell from the limited information I gave and suggested using Fiddler. So I added an edit to my question with further details pulled from using Fiddler.

My original question received four answers shortly after it was posted, and after I edited the question to specify further diagnostics, it does not seem to have received new replies.

What should I do in the future if I post question X, and later have additional information Y to include? Are there appropriate ways to draw more responses?

Comment: See also [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)

Comment: @bobobobo why remove that tag? It is appropriate

Comment: Because it was an unpopular tag (was used on only [1 other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)), so I deleted the tag on both questions.  Besides that, it's kind of ambiguous as a tag name (should I `pay-attention` to `attention` posts, or are they about gathering an audience?)

Answer (score 6):

You can post a bounty or ask a new question.  Be careful with the new question option, though, as it might be seen as a duplicate if they're too similar.  Usually if you post a link to the original and state that the new question is a follow-up people are pretty understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Start a bounty.  I've found this to be extremely effective at raising an old question from the dead (although you don't get many answers until right when the bounty is about to expire).

Answer (score 2):

Editing a question with new information will tend to put it back up to the front page on the active questions tab, but I know most people tend to focus on the New Questions tab. Starting a bounty seems like one logical way to do it. Another way would be to create a new question, as long as it wasn't an exact duplicate of what you were asking (in other words, craft your new question so that it incorporates what you now know so that you don't hit the same potholes you were in before).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem.

Users that browse through questions using the "Active" tab may encounter your recently modified question, but users that mainly go through "Newest" (like me) wouldn't.

If the question really got no answers, I don't think there's anything wrong with deleting it and reposting with newer, more complete information.

Comment: Maybe just close it instead?