# Help getting unanswered questions answered

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

When I posted [my first SO question][1], I was happy to finally have something to ask!  ...until I got only two answers, and one of them was from me.  I haven't accepted my answer yet because it has no upvotes, and I'm still wondering if it's even the best way.  The other answer is more of a suggestion to look into something than an actual *answer*.

I've tried rewriting the question for more clarity and also to get it bumped back to the top of the list.  What else can be done to try to get more answers?

Comment: Have you considered adding ponies to it?  That seems to do the trick here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "edit and re-word" is definitely a good idea.

If you have enough rep, bounty is an option... but you don't have the rep... yet!

You mention "code behind" in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809078). If this is ASP.NET, try adding the asp.net tag; that will get you a different audience.

Additional:

- you've nearly got 100 on your SO
- when that happens, [associate it to your MSO account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) for another +100
- then you can [place a bounty](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/)

So here's a thought; have a look at the [current questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions); help **somebody else** out with a good/helpful answer, and you should easily get the last 30 points you need to commence your master plan ;-p

Comment: Awesome, way to take the extra step and hunt down my example question!

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned on other questions (I believe by Marc Gravell as well), since you are still working on your question yourself, you can add more context as you find more information. So your 'edit and re-word' will also make the question easier to answer (which is good for us lazy programmers).

Furthermore, you may dig deeper and discover that your original question is just a surface problem for a more deep rooted issue, in which case you can ask a second question (as long as they are actually *different*). Once that happens, you may be able to answer your own first question, and take ALL the rep associated. Muahahahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

The definitive FAQ for this on SO is [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me a lot of the suggestion for question bumping, which would allow for users to bump up topics which they feel didn't get a good look the first time around. Of course re-wording the question in some fashion through an edit process would also bump, so this may be moot. Just reminded me.

[Please add a way to 'bump' questions back to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/feature-request-question-bumping)