# My only unsolved problem

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help getting unanswered questions answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/help-getting-unanswered-questions-answered)

I've asked many questions (about 100) and there was only one, rather recent, question that didn't get a prompt solution. So it's incredible how much SO helps a lone programmer getting blind on his own code or eager to learn a new tool or technology.

But what should I do with my single one question I already asked and still pursue the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537545/why-the-conflicting-variables).

I suppose obvious next step would be a bounty but then I don't know. Do you have any specific thoughts about my situation?

Comment: If you're still pursuing the answer, why have you already accepted an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You've got several questions with zero answers not just one, and as Peter says, you've accepted an answer to the linked question. If your question is just "how do I promote this question to get more info", the answer is obviously add a bounty, and I again don't know what you're asking that is specific / additional to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a (big) bounty would increase the visibility of your question, particularly if you're looking for better answers. However, the presence of an accepted answer might decrease the willingness of others to add answers.