# Questions becoming stale after a short period of time

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Occasionally I will post a message and realize that I worded it wrong, especially if it gets downvoted.  I go back and edit it, but 20 minutes have passed and people are no longer looking at the question because it's no longer at the top of the stack.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Question quite similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, anything that bumps a post back on the front page will get visits; you just have to look at how quickly people will re-open a "fixed" post (quite quickly), or jump on inappropriate edits.

YMMV depending on site activity of course, but ***generally*** I don't see an issue here - i.e. a bumped question does get read. Indeed, the "community" account randomly bumps unanswered questions to exploit this.

Answer (score 1):

Once a question is in negative territory, it will be very hard I think to get significant visibility for it even if it is updated.  The exceptions are those that are downvoted because they are controversial.  These do seem to retain quite a life.  Perhaps you could try changing the title -- "new and improved" -- to highlight that the question has been edited when you have questions with downvotes.

As @Marc says, if you edit it, it should reappear on the front page and get more views.  Unfortunately, with downvotes I don't know how much this will actually help.