# Should I re-ask an old question if the answer(s) aren't acceptable?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Can I re-ask a question if it hasn’t been answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered)
> [How can new users get old unresolved questions answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13019/how-can-new-users-get-old-unresolved-questions-answered)
> [What if my question is technically a duplicate, but the original question was never answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38547/what-if-my-question-is-technically-a-duplicate-but-the-original-question-was-nev)

I have a question I'd like to ask, but an exact duplicate exists. It was asked by another user and has an accepted answer (unsatisfactory for me) more than a year ago.

Is it acceptable to re-ask the question in hopes that a year has brought some additional insight or suggestions?

Should I just bump the original question as [suggested here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-reask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered)?

#### See also:

- [Can I re-ask a question if it hasn’t been answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-reask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered)
- [What if my question is technically a duplicate, but the original question was never answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38547/what-if-my-question-is-technically-a-duplicate-but-the-original-question-was-never-answered)
- [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13019/how-can-new-users-get-old-unresolved-questions-answered

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> has an accepted answer (unsatisfactory for me)

That right there proves that it's *not* an exact duplicate.  So when asking your question, focus on whatever difference exists that makes this other answer not work.

Comment: While probable, not entirely true, as the accepted answer is awarded by the choice of an individual. (All I'm saying is that it doesn't _prove it_)

Comment: @Downvoter - it does prove the two askers have different problems, but the first asker may not have included all the information and so you're right the questions as asked my be duplicates.

Comment: I'm with downvoter on this. Sometime askers accept sub-optimal answers---accepted doesn't mean best or even good. That does not mean that the answer the potentially new asker wants isn't present on the original. *Certainly* focus on the why the answers to the older question are not acceptable if the correct answer does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I say re-ask it; while technically you should bump the old question chances are you won't get any news answers if it already has established (ie, upvoted) answers out of which one was accepted.

Maybe try to phrase it a bit differently and mention at the end that you found the possible duplicate but that its answer wasn't satisfactory for you.