# How to resurrect my question once it has been buried?

Tags: support, questions

My question very quickly disappeared after posting it as there were too many new posts coming in at the time. So I reckon this is one of the reasons why not many people have viewed it so far.
Is there a way to get my question on top the list again?

Comment: This has been covered before - will try to dig out links.

Comment: This has been discussed before. For the recommended approach(es) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page/8317#8317

Comment: @mas - beat me to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the canonical answer is still

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the user sorts their list. If they sort by activity, your question is bumped to the top everytime you make an edit to it, someone answers, etc. If they sort by post date, it's not.

That said, you should **not** get the idea to constantly bump the question by editing. That will pretty fast be noticed and probably considered suspiciously spammy behaviour.

Here's my advice: Have a little patience. Your question is not gone when it's off the first page, and people will still find it. Some people subscribe to RSS feeds of a particular tag they are interested in, some people browse around, etc. Some might even already be in the middle of doing research to answer your question.

It's not unusual for a question to last a while before it gets answered.

Answer (score 1):

Be patient.

After a while, if you still get no answers and low views, reap the rewards of a Tumbleweed badge. It's badgelicious!

Or if you've come across new information, edit your original question and this will bump it to the top of the eyeball pile. Any new answers to your question will also float it back up in the acitivity pile. But don't get all edit crazy, that's frown upon.

Asking a well-formed question always helps as well. Read more about [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions).

But also keep in mind that there are plenty of users, thousands even, who don't view the front page and instead just follow their own favoured set of tags. Your question will pop up in that view stream and get an answer.

Don't bank on the front page or the first page as the be all and end all to where the attention is for questions.