# Wouln't it be cool if you could bump just once?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a way to 'bump' questions back to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page)

I know how much of i nightmare it would be if you where able to bump up a question...

But i often find myself posting a question, and while waiting for answers, realizes that my question should have bin asked differently and next thing you know, your question is 30 questions from the top in your category with no answers, and then you write a new question that is slightly different, but almost the same,and that turns out great with lot's of answers.

If you where able to bump you questions just once, and maybe only do so 3 times a day, and maybe it cots you some points to do it, or something. I think you could prevent a lot of questions being posted twice.

Comment: You can sort of do this, just edit the question.

Answer (score 11):

No, it wouldn't be cool.  The Stack Exchange sites have mechanisms to get questions that haven't gotten enough attention bumped on their own.

Also a bounty can be offered up to get attention for a question.

Finally, all posts have a "share" link which gives you a link to promote a question (or answer) on various social sites, or wherever you want to post the link, which should garner more views, and possibly answers.

That said, performing a minor edit just to get the post noticed, without fixing anything substantial for the sole purpose of getting more attention for the question is considered an abuse of the edit system.  If you do this, expect moderator action to be taken.

Comment: This information should *absolutely* be taken into account before following the advice of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can bump, numerous times.

Simply edit the question, adding additional, *useful information* to it that will help it attract answers.

You can also add a bounty to increase a question's visibility even more.

Just be sure you do not overuse editing in this way; give your question some time, and be sure you have quality edits to add. (Credit to nhahtdh for this addition, see comment below)

Comment: Just don't overuse it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142851/my-question-was-removed-how-can-i-still-retrieve-its-valuable-content

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks :)

Comment: @nhahtdh Good additional point! I've added a note

Comment: Emphasis on *useful* information!

Comment: @razlebe Yes, sir! (hehe... good idea to emphasize that, so I have)

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, didn't intend that to read as a barked command. :) Though now that I know it works, I'm off to try it elsewhere...