# Feature to 'POP Up' a question

Tags: feature-request, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a way to 'bump' questions back to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page)

I used to be part of communities on Orkut, where when a question would not get enough responses, and get pilled down by other questions, thread starter would make a blank post [called as pop up post], just to bring the question on the top, and get some attention again.

I was wondering if some similar feature could be added to SO where, if there has been an x amount of time, and user is still not happy with the available answers, he could 'Pop' the question up, so that some more people might see it ?

Comment: And please don't ask 'Whats Orkut?'. That hurts :(

Comment: What's Orkut? <-- had to be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This already exists. If a question gets updated to improve it, it will be bumped up again. (Don't abuse this feature though with trivial edits. That is not appreciated).

Questions with not enough attention also get bumped from time to time by the [community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

And if that still does not help, you an always [add a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) to your question.

Comment: Exactly, a bump post is not exactly considered polite.